# Error refreshing the OAuth2 token @ Google_CalendarServices (php)

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

i know there are many similar questions, where the 'invalid_grant' is the only 'answer' we got from google api, but all them are old, or discussing different ways of getting to the same message.

The weird part is, that this 'thing' only stopped working for 2 days ago. In our CRM we book meetings into GoogleCalendars associated with our GoogleAccount. Now in the last 2 days we are experiencing problems, never happend before.

The application fails like this:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{"error" : "invalid_grant";}

Stack trace:

#0 /path/to/plugins/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(240): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)
#1 /path/to/plugins/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(217): Google_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/ourtoken...')
#2 /path/to/plugins/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(167): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#3 /path/to/plugins/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php(494): Google_ServiceResource->__call('insert', Array)
```

This is the actual http answer:

```
Google_HttpRequest Object
(
    [batchHeaders:Google_HttpRequest:private] => Array
        (
            [Content-Type] => application/http
            [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => binary
            [MIME-Version] => 1.0
            [Content-Length] => 
        )

    [url:protected] => https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
    [requestMethod:protected] => POST
    [requestHeaders:protected] => Array
        (
            [content-type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            [content-length] => 196
        )

    [postBody:protected] => client_id=111111111.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=secretSECTRETsecretSECRET&refresh_token=1%2FveryLONGtokenSTRINGhafbuaADDFR&grant_type=refresh_token
    [userAgent:protected] => Google Calendar PHP Starter Application google-api-php-client/0.6.0
    [responseHttpCode:protected] => 400
    [responseHeaders:protected] => Array
        (
            [content-type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
            [cache-control] => no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
            [pragma] => no-cache
            [expires] => Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
            [date] => Thu, 10 Nov 2016 01:05:15 GMT
            [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
            [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
            [x-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block
            [server] => GSE
            [alt-svc] => quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34"
            [accept-ranges] => none
            [vary] => Accept-Encoding
            [transfer-encoding] => chunked
        )

    [responseBody:protected] => {
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
    [accessKey] => 
)
```

Yes we are using an older version not anything new. Yes the account is live, the calendar into which we are trying to insert is existing. No privileges or passwords were changed/reset. We tried all our calendars - no success at all. And i tried also some minor changes/hacks I found here like not using developer key, set access type to offline, synchronizing server time and so on...

Actually we did nothing with the whole thing before it broke. So there is one question: did Google changed something in the behaviour/code or something? Or did we miss something (like deprecated/deleted functions)?

**EDIT #1**

One of my colleges did change something in fact. (More on that at the end of edit section)

So we have one 'main' google account, wit developer key and clientid and everything -> and this account also has 1 calendar.

Than we have multiple other google accounts for our co-workers. We have grants from main calendar to their calendars and vice-versa. In our CMS we try to add an event (hence insert on Google_CalendarService) to one of the co-workers calendar.

So one of our co-workers quit the job, and my college change **HIS** password. And removed grants. Well it happend Monday at 16:00 and Tuesday morning we got the first error. Could this one google account's change affect the behaviour of all other, resp. the behaviour of the main calendar account???

**-- end of EDIT #1**

If anyone experienced something similar like this and managed to fix, please give some advise. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using one of the Gmail scopes? Any chance the user changed their password recently?  "Google changed something in the behaviour/code or something?"  I am not sure but I have seen a large number of questions like this the last few weeks.  I have a Google contact checking into it.

Comment: Hi @DaImTo, thank you for your comment. we are not defining any scope explicitly, I'll edit the description to give you a little bit more information of the usage. A feedback from your google guy will be very nice. Cheers

Comment: Let me be more clear.  You must at least be requesting the google calendar scope when authenticating your users.  Are you requesting any other permissions?

Comment: To be clear: The only fix is to request authentication again.   Google has expired the refresh token there is no way to fix that.   The real question here is: Why did google expire your refresh token?  that's what we are trying to figure out.

Comment: Ok, I got you, but we never used scopes before, and if I have to define one, which one exactly should I choose? No other permission requests. Really just one insert is all we do there. An insert into one of the co-workers google calendar - which is of course not the changed one...

Comment: How do I re-authenticate? Must be done in the main account or in the sub accounts? :P

Comment: which ever one you used to create the refresh token in question.  Probably the user who you are trying to write to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news everyone (who cares at all)!

After endless digging and try&fails, I found out that google had in fact blocked our old access token. Maybe it was the password change and grant removal from our side, maybe it was the ex-co-workers attempt to revoke or reset something, not sure. But the token was not active anymore.

After some small challanges with the Oauth2 Playground I've set up a connection with our API credentials, and got the new connection preferences (new access token and new refresh tokens)

Special thanks and a big shout out to @DaImTo for pointing out, that it's probably the inactive/old token what is causing this issue.

@Google: please add meaningful error messages and error descriptions, it will be much cooler to lose some minutes to hours as 2-3 days to solve 'minor' but critical issues like this one!

I hope this post will help someone once in the future. Peace!

Answer (score 1):

11/17/2016 Update:

We did find an issue that resulted in some tokens being purged. We are working on to make sure it doesn't happen again. Unfortunately there is no way to restore the tokens that were deleted and your users will have to reauthorize again.

---

We (Google Identity team) are investigating the issue as a few other developers have contacted us as well. In order to speed up debugging, 
could you IM me through my G+ profile so I can get some info and investigate.

"did Google changed something in the behaviour/code or something? " the answer is no there was no intentional change.

Comment: As per my tracking of this issue its not all of them but a random subset of the.   Most of the time its refresh tokens that have been used at least two weeks before suddenly not working.  I haven't been able to recreate it yet.   Wild guess could it have something to do with the resent time change?  Although It has never been an issue previous years.

Comment: @nvnagr I sent you invitation on hangouts, not sure if that's what you wanted. Donno to be honest if it's one token ore more. I have one account integrated (the main account) into our system and that tries to insert events into others calendars -> is it than 1 token, or 1 token respectively per calendar? But none of them is working -> cant even insert event into the main account's calendar. (I mean the calendar of the same account, of which I am doing the new Google_Client() instance)

Comment: Elzo, Agree this is not the traditional "good" answer but this allowed even other developers who saw this question with similar issues to contact me. The other answer to this question is not accurate. I can say that as my team  runs the OAuth services at Google.  I'll edit this answer once we investigate  the issue.

Comment: @nvnagr we are noticing a significant increase in revoking (10x) of refresh_tokens over the last two weeks. As best as we can tell this does not look to be an issue on our side. What is the best way to get in contact with you? I couldn't see how to IM you on G+.

Comment: @DaImTo we noticed exactly the issue you describe just before daylight savings changed (if that's what you mean by recent time change).

Comment: @nvnagr the other answer is in fact not answering the question what happend by google that they deleted/blocked our token, but it provides a solution for the problem  stated in the description/question. And its accurate, because I wrote down what I did in order to bring it back to life. Whereas your answer provided answer "NO" but didn't solve anything :D

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with an old app I made. By regenerating the client secret and developer key just to be safe the app works again, anything else you will try will fail. Sadly a wasted morning.